# The difference between analysis and real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I do not know the difference between analysis and real analysis.

When I study analysis, is it alright if I use the books on real analysis?

Comment: Yes, it's a good start!

Comment: In introductory university courses, I think the terms are synonymous.

Comment: It may depend on the context you are seeing these words in. Are you studying "analysis" for a course? If so, what is the title of the course? What is the course description from the syllabus? Providing more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Real analysis is analysis in the real number system. Analysis without the qualifier may refer to real analysis. Contrast with the many books on complex analysis, which is analysis in the complex number system. Whether you can use books on real analysis to study analysis depends on the topic of the class, but if this is your first analysis course it is probably real analysis.